# WPF forms that returns an object on .Close()

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am working on this, I have a Database, and when someone presses the "Search" button it opens a prompt where he/she enters the Name or ID of what he is looking for. Then, a Lambda expression finds the right object in the database and put it in a function for the Main function to use.

But there is my problem, the main function do not wait for the property to be "not null" and instead takes the null value, so nothing happens.

I've looked up every single Google result (on the first page) on every possible formulation I could come up with. DialogResult does not return an object.

Thank you.

Here's my code if you want to take a look  :

```
//In the main function (well main WPF window)
Recherche recherche = new Recherche("film", (this.rbIdentifiant.IsChecked == true ? true : false));
if (recherche.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    ClientsListView.ScrollIntoView(recherche.Obj);
}
//In the prompt
private string _sType;
private bool _bType;
public object Obj { get; private set; }
public Recherche(string sType, bool bType)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _sType = sType;
    _bType = bType;
    if (bType)
        this._lblTypeRecherche.Content = "ID";
    else
        this._lblTypeRecherche.Content = "Nom/Titre:";
}
private void _btnRecherche_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     using (var db = new DBaseContainer())
     {
         if (_sType == "film" && _bType)
         {
             int iId = this._txtRecherche.Text.ToInt();
             var film = db.Films.Where(x => x.FilmId == iId);
              Obj = film.First();
         }
          if (_sType == "film" && !_bType)
         {
             var film = db.Films.Where(x => x.Titre ==  this._txtRecherche.Text);
             Obj = film.First();
         }
          if (_sType == "client" && _bType)
         {
             int iId = this._txtRecherche.Text.ToInt();
             var client = db.Clients.Where(x => x.ClientId == iId);
             Obj = client.First();
         }
          if (_sType == "client" && !_bType)
         {
             var client = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Nom == this._txtRecherche.Text);
             Obj = client.First();
         }
     }
     this.Close();
  }
```

Comment: Delete all that and use proper DataBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you've two ways of handling this. Either, you use an event on the `recherche` control and do your stuff in there. (the `sender` object of the event should be the window/control).

Or you use a `while` loop on the `.Visibility` property of the control.

If `Recherche` inherits from `Window` this would work just fine:

```
Recherche recherche = new Recherche("film", (this.rbIdentifiant.IsChecked == true ? true : false));
recherche.Closed += (o, e) => {ClientsListView.ScrollIntoView((o as Recherche).Obj);};
```

Comment: Intellisense doesn't like your use of "e" as a variable. I changed it to f, doesn't seem to work. But you gave me part of the answer with "recherche.Closed" so thank you :)

Comment: weird, that should work. Could you post the exact error message? The EventHandler delegate has two parameters, so the anonymous/lambda method needs two parameters as well.